# insert using a variable of a consult php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to perform an insert with the information of a query from another table, using php and mysql, I know that I have not done the protection part against sql injection correctly, I will solve that at the end, I tell you why then they only go to scold and do not contribute, would you be kind enough to tell me how to use the value obtained from the query, thank you.

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include("conection.php");

$credits = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['credits']);
$namesec = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['namesec']);
$change = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['change']);



$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE students 
  SET student_credits = (student_credits + ?) 
  WHERE student_qr = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $_POST['credits'], $_POST['namesec']);
$stmt->execute();

$insert_query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO historical_credits (id_students, credits_paid)
    SELECT id_students, ?
    FROM students
    WHERE student_qr = ?"
);
$insert_query->bind_param("is", $_POST['credits'], $_POST['namesec']);
$insert_query->execute();

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want to use the value of id_student obtained from the query to insert it into a new table

Comment: You forgot to do `$row = $search_query->fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Using prepare with PHP string variable interpolation is kind of _weird_ and defeating the use?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `fetch_assoc()` to get the row that the query returns.

You also didn't quote `$namesec` in the `SELECT` query, so it's getting an error. This wouldn't be a problem if you used a parameter instead of substituting the variable.

But there's no need to do this in two queries. You can give a `SELECT` query as the source of the data in `INSERT`.

```
$insert_query = $con->prepare("
    INSERT INTO historical_credits (id_students, credits_paid)
    SELECT id_students, ?
    FROM students
    WHERE student_qr = ?");
$insert_query->bind_param("is", $_POST['credits'], $_POST['namesec']);
$insert_query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are great, just one more annoyance, could you guide me on how to carry out two queries, that is, do the one you indicated and one more, is it possible or do I need to separate the files? this since I want to do an update in another table

Comment: There's nothing special about doing multiple queries. You don't need multiple files.

Comment: I have edited my question to know if this would be a solution, using what you taught me about bind param, is it correct or am I lost?

Comment: `WHERE student_qr = $?` should be `WHERE student_qr = ?`

Comment: thanks I have made the change you told me and if it worked like this, sorry it was already blocked yesterday